# Evaluate the line integral of $\frac{1}{z-a}$ over $\gamma$, where $\gamma=a+Re^{it}$, $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$ and a is a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am having some trouble trying to understand how to deal with the gamma and in general how to fit this into the typical formula.  Can anyone help me here out suggest some better way to visualize it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Since $dz=iRe^{it}dt$ on $\gamma_R$ (counterclockwise), you may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\Large \gamma}\frac{1}{z-a} dz&=\int_{\large 0}^{\large 2\pi}\frac{1}{R\:e^{it}}\:iRe^{it}dt\\\\
&=\int_{\large 0}^{\large 2\pi}i\:dt\\\\
&=2\pi i.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: *Hint*? answer!

Comment: @Walter There is no proof here...

Comment: A proof was not asked for ...